# how can I pass colors of container in search method

Tags: flutter

```
            ? AppBar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                title: TextField(
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      print("000$value");
                      setState(() {
                        if (value.isNotEmpty) {
                          serchlist = [];
                          for (int u = 0; u < notedata.length; u++) {
                            String title = notedata[u]['TITLE'];
                            String subject = notedata[u]['NOTES'];
                            int color = notedata[u]['COLORS'];
                            if (title
                                    .toLowerCase()
                                    .contains(value.toLowerCase()) ||
                                subject
                                    .toUpperCase()
                                    .contains(value.toUpperCase()) ) {
                              print("111$title");
                              serchlist.add(notedata[u]);
                            } else {}
                          }
                        } else {
                          serchlist = notedata;
                        }
                      });
                    },
                    autofocus: true,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      hintText: " search",
                      suffixIcon: IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              issearch = false;
                            });
                          },
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.close,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          )),
                    )),
              )
            : AppBar(
                leading: IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.menu)),
                actions: [
                  IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          issearch = true;
                        });
                      },
                      icon: Icon(Icons.search_sharp)),
                  IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert)),
                ],
                backgroundColor: Colors.orange.shade500,
                elevation: 5,
                title: Text("Notes",
                    style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "regular", fontSize: 26))),
```

how I pass colors of container in search method.

Comment: formate your code before posting question. check out my answer. happy coding :)

Comment: cant see Container

Answer (score 0):

edit your code checkout bellow code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool issearch = true;
  List<Map> serchlist = [];
  List<int> colorlist = [];
  List<Map> notedata = [
    {
      'TITLE': "yellow",
      'NOTES': "notes1",
      'COLORS': 4,
    },
    {
      'TITLE': "blue",
      'NOTES': "notes1",
      'COLORS': 3,
    },
    {
      'TITLE': "red",
      'NOTES': "notes1",
      'COLORS': 2,
    }
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    serchlist = notedata;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: issearch
          ? AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              title: TextField(
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      if (value.isNotEmpty) {
                        serchlist = [];
                        for (int u = 0; u < notedata.length; u++) {
                          String title = notedata[u]['TITLE'];
                          String subject = notedata[u]['NOTES'];
                          int color = notedata[u]['COLORS'];
                          if (title
                                  .toLowerCase()
                                  .contains(value.toLowerCase()) ||
                              subject
                                  .toUpperCase()
                                  .contains(value.toUpperCase()) ||
                              color.toString().contains(value.toLowerCase())) {
                            serchlist.add(notedata[u]);
                            colorlist.add(color);
                          }
                        }
                      } else {
                        serchlist = notedata;
                      }
                      setState(() {});
                    });
                  },
                  autofocus: true,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    icon: const Text(""),
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    hintText: " search",
                    suffixIcon: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            issearch = false;
                          });
                        },
                        icon: const Icon(
                          Icons.close,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        )),
                  )),
            )
          : AppBar(
              leading:
                  IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.menu)),
              actions: [
                IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        issearch = true;
                      });
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.search_sharp)),
                IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.more_vert)),
              ],
              backgroundColor: Colors.orange.shade500,
              elevation: 5,
              title: const Text("Notes",
                  style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "regular", fontSize: 26))),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: serchlist.length,
            itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
              return Card(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text("TITLE ${serchlist[index]['TITLE'] ?? ""}"),
                      Text(
                          "NOTES ${serchlist[index]['NOTES'] as String ?? ""}"),
                      Text("COLORS ${serchlist[index]['COLORS'] as int ?? 0}"),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: ok but in search only pass value not a colors.

Comment: so you want all keys while search ? i m not getting you. can you explain me in details what is your expected output?

Comment: i made a database for title subject and color. so that are show in listview but in search only show title and subject and color was not show by index.

Comment: so user can also search via colors value too correct?

Comment: can you share you color value ? base on this int color = notedata[u]['COLORS']; this line i belive that your colors data type is int. so it may be any value but for demo i added numbers

Comment: yes i want all keys while search..

Comment: okay  let me update my answer.

Comment: answer updated. now search function will work for all keys (title, notes & colors).
you need to just add one more OR condition in TextField onChanged event. checkout my answer.

Comment: accept answer if correct

Answer (score 0):

**Send any of the three parameter through search and get result from the server**

As from the problem I understand user can search by colour,subject or titles simply let user put any of the things as input and you can search from the database which ever parameter it matches and then return it to the API or user. But make sure you have implemented this on server side.